# SpringSession and redis always rename sessionKey in redis

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

i am using the SpringSecurity,SpringSession and redis

When I logged into three accounts, SpringSession added three pieces of data to Redis

But the previous account was renamed by the later account

i unable to use the eventListener and unable to use the findByPrincipalName

```
23:05:37.210 [http-nio-9001-exec-1] INFO  com.revers.config.LoginSuccess - [onAuthenticationSuccess,25] - 123
23:05:37.317 [springSessionRedisMessageListenerContainer-1] INFO  com.revers.listener.KeyExpiredListener - [processSessionCreatedEvent,27] - created
23:05:37.317 [springSessionRedisMessageListenerContainer-1] INFO  com.revers.listener.KeyExpiredListener - [processSessionCreatedEvent,28] - 278a951c-e048-4326-afb3-f299d37832d5 (account1's session ID)
23:05:38.684 [http-nio-9001-exec-2] INFO  com.revers.config.LoginSuccess - [onAuthenticationSuccess,25] - 1234
23:05:40.241 [http-nio-9001-exec-3] INFO  com.revers.config.LoginSuccess - [onAuthenticationSuccess,25] - 12345
expire key:spring:session:sessions:expires:8c00a1a7-7317-48b4-9a4d-07fae7637a9f (account3's session ID)
23:06:40.460 [springSessionRedisMessageListenerContainer-6] INFO  com.revers.listener.KeyExpiredListener - [processSessionDestroyedEvent,41] - destroyed
23:06:40.460 [springSessionRedisMessageListenerContainer-6] INFO  com.revers.listener.KeyExpiredListener - [processSessionDestroyedEvent,42] - 8c00a1a7-7317-48b4-9a4d-07fae7637a9f
23:06:40.460 [springSessionRedisMessageListenerContainer-6] INFO  com.revers.listener.KeyExpiredListener - [processSessionExpiredEvent,48] - expired
23:06:40.460 [springSessionRedisMessageListenerContainer-6] INFO  com.revers.listener.KeyExpiredListener - [processSessionExpiredEvent,49] - 8c00a1a7-7317-48b4-9a4d-07fae7637a9f
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZYhq.png)

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

- purpose

  - i want get session in redis when session is alive , how to cancel renaming
  - or use the eventListener  to listen every session's create and destroyed